# Using TypeScript for WebComponent with Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, web-component

I have an angular application created in the default way using `ng new project-name"`. For performance reasons, I had to create and integrate single standard WebComponents. The related Javascript code is stored in a folder "web-components" located in the **app** folder. Everything works finde - accessing the pure WebComponents from Angular components is possible and `ng build` automatically recreates the Angular app if any of the WebComponent's Javascript files are changed.

But to improve the development process I would like to write also the non-Angular WebComponents in Typescript. So the WebComponent's Typescript code should be translated to Javascript automatically within the Angular project. But up to now, I didn't find a way how to reach this goal within an Angular project. So if anybody has any suggestions on how to set up the Angular project such that this transpiring is done automatically.

Comment: I've done this with ```Polymer3.0``` and ```Angular```, in your ```app.module.ts``` file, add the ```CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA``` to your ```schemas``` property of your ```AppModule```

Answer (score 0):

There is a library called [Stencil JS](https://stenciljs.com/), which is essentially allow you to build web component that will work in any major JS framework such as Angular, React and Vue. Here is how [component build with Stencil will integrate with Angular](https://stenciljs.com/docs/angular)

I'm in the process of creating component library using this at the company I work, and have some success. The best part of this approach is that you have to think in isolation when you build components. If you are OK with building generic web component in separate place (separate repo) and use npm and webpack to bundle it, then you might want to check this out!

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion, but I think it's a bit of "overkill" to introduce an additional library for the described task. As transpiring TS code to JS code is an essential building block for Angular, I am convinced that there exists a quite simple way for doing the same task with web components ...